# Cant find "Manage Data Integration" option on User

Tags: integration, user, data, bulk-permission

1. Logged in as "System Administrator"
2. Searched for particular User (XYZ123)
3. Can't find "Manage Data Integration" option here ?

Any Suggestions ! Am I missing something ? 
Do I have to check-on another option too, to see this option ?

List of user Permissions : 
http://www.cloudmurali.com/?p=1330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this under **Profile-> System permissions**

[image]

So go to the profile of User(XYZ123) and search it in the System permissions.

**Edit**: Same permission can be provided through permission set as well(If you only want to give this to small number of users). In permission set also it is listed under System permissions

Comment: But checking this ON on profile level will give permission to all user's of that profile, am I right ?

Comment: Definately. But if you want to give this permission only to some users you can create a permission set and can provide this permission in that.

Comment: The same permission is available in permission set as well under system permissions.

Comment: Got it, Thanks, Please mention "use Permission Set (for particular user)" in answer too. So that I can accept it.

Comment: I have updated the answer.